# jquery datepicker css issue

Tags: jquery, css, datetimepicker

I'm using datetimepicker by trentrichardson.com and edited to give a green color to few days' cell at my choice with this css (through the beforeShowDay) :

```
 .busyday {background-color:#F90 !important; }   
 .busyday a { opacity: 0.7 !important;}
```

The css is working on Chrome but both IE and firefox dont show any style change..

Anybody have had this issue before?

**EDITED:**

According to this tutorial page (that I used to improve my datepicker)I'm not the only one getting the strange result

[TUTORIAL](http://stevethomas.com.au/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ajax-request-to-highlight-days-from-mysql.html/comment-page-1)

thanks

Luca

Comment: by the way, #F90 is orange, and not green

Answer (score 2):

Add a whitespace before `!important`

Comment: Do you use an external css-file ? If yes be sure that it's not loaded from cache after the change.

Comment: yep.. but still not seeing any difference..and since chrome is the only one showing "correct" somewhere i should be wrong =(

Comment: So that's not enough information you provide, the background-color should be applied in FF+IE too, the opacity only in FF as long as IE doesn't support "opacity" (except IE9 in standards mode)